# how to change data via key not index in a dropdown in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following prototype code.  it is a dropdown that contains key values used to change a pie chart and it works.  But in my actual code I need to select by the key not the index of the data. seems like it should be easy, I am just missing it. So to restate: the code uses the index of the dropdown and I need it to use the actual key [the value of the dropdown] instead.

The code in question is where the change function is used.

```js
// fake data
// data.tsv
//region fruit count
//East Apples 53245
//West Apples 28479
//South Apples 19697
//North Apples 24037
//Central Apples 40245
//East Oranges 200
//South Oranges 200
//Central Oranges 200






var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
    .sort(null);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 20);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  var regionsByFruit = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.fruit; })
      .entries(data)
      .reverse();

 var select = d3.select("form").append("div")
     .append("select")
     .on("change", function() { 
change(regionsByFruit[d3.event.target.selectedIndex]); })
     .selectAll("option")
     .data(regionsByFruit)
     .enter()
     .append("option");

  select.selectAll("option")
      //.attr("type", "radio")
      .attr("name", "fruit")
      .attr("value", function(d) { return d.key; })
      .filter(function(d, i) { return !i; });
    
  select.append("span")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
   
  function change(region) {
    var data0 = path.data(),
        data1 = pie(region.values);

    path = path.data(data1, key);

    path.enter().append("path")
        .each(function(d, i) { this._current = findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) || d; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.region); })
      .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.region; });

    path.exit()
        .datum(function(d, i) { return findNeighborArc(i, data1, data0, key) || d; })
      .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween)
        .remove();

    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  }
});

function key(d) {
  return d.data.region;
}

function type(d) {
  d.count = +d.count;
  return d;
}

function findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var d;
  return (d = findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.endAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}
      : (d = findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.startAngle}
      : null;
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the highest preceding element in data1.
function findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var m = data0.length;
  while (--i >= 0) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the lowest following element in data1.
function findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var n = data1.length, m = data0.length;
  while (++i < n) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}

function arcTween(d) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
}
```

```css
ody {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

input {
  margin: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form></form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you make a working fiddle or plunkr? Not only because it saves our time, but because we can provide you an exact answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not run the code you provided but I managed to tweak it in order to achieve what I think you wanted. The approach I took was the following:

```
var select = d3.select("form").append("div")
.append("select")
.on('change', updatePie) // run this fn when select value changes


function updatePie(d, i) {
    var selectedFruit = this.value; // get the value of the selected option which is your key
    var newData = regionsByFruit.filter(function(value) { // filter data so you only get the data with the given key
        return value.key === selectedFruit;
    });
    // Update data in elements
    var updatee = svg.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(newData[0].values)); 
    // Do exit, update and addition of nodes logic
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EruBcbvZ6QhBVZXKOFSf?p=preview

Comment: Did you check the plunker I made? Is that what you want to do or is it something way off?

Comment: above is the existing code, it was fixed while i prepared it :-)

Comment: looking at it now torresomar  looks good.  will test thanks!!

Comment: torresomar -  looking at your code, just had a question:  the update pie function takes a d and an i as parameters (d,i ) but the on change signature shows the updatePie function without parameters WHY or HOW does this work? thanks

Comment: In my example I'm just setting the reference to the function I want to use at the desired event, the documentation of d3 says the following "When a specified event is dispatched on a selected node, the specified listener will be invoked for each selected element, being passed the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element." so it will basically call the function with d and i as args and setting the context as the DOM element.